# Interpretation of a claim in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

**Theorem**  For a connected nontrivial graph with exactly $2k$ odd vertices, the minimum number of trails that decompose it is $\max\{k,1\}$.

> For me the formulation of the claim leaves room to two interpretations
>
> 1. There are $2k$ odd vertices; exactly means "no even vertex"
> 2. There are $2k$ odd vertices and zero or more even vertex; exactly means "$2k$ odd vertices and no one more"
>
> Is the claim vague or is my English understanding vague?

Comment: My interpretation of this is 2., but I am not a native English speaker either. I have generally found that the statement "exactly _x_ things of type _a_" mean just that -  _x_ things of type _a_, and no information about the number of things of other types, leaving room for other types to exist.

Comment: @Emilia314 thank you

Answer (score 1):

It means the latter, any number of vertices of even degree are permitted.

Compare/contrast: "My head contains exactly two eyes."  The word "exactly" is modifying "two", not "contains".  One way to see this is to delete modifiers to see what meaning (if any) survives.

- "My head contains two eyes."  True.  Of course, if my head contained four eyes, this statement is still true.  "Exactly" must be a leaf in the dependency graph of the sentence.
- "My head contains exactly eyes."  Mangled.  There may exist a context where a distinction between approximate eyes and exact eyes is meaningful, but I don't know of one.

Compare/contrast: "My bag exactly contains two books."  "Exactly" now modifies "contains" and informs the reader that there are zero non-books and two books in the bag.

Comment: The whole thing is around the qualifier "odd/even". Your example does not contain it. The equivalent would be "My head contains exactly two green eyes", and the question, then is "has his head also some brown eye?"

Comment: @AaronLenz : No.  The whole thing is exactly what is "exactly" modifying.